# JSP Page becomes too long to get compile

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP page . With the course of time it has become very long somehow.

Recently i was compiling the jsp page and i got an exception from the compiler that

```
   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

   An error occurred at line: 320 in the generated java file
   The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
```

What should I do to avoid this exception.?

Answer (score 6):

During JSP compilation, the entire body of a JSP file will be placed inside a single `try` block. The limit which a Java block can contain is 64KB. The size of the generated Java code of your JSP file apparently exceeded that.

Perhaps you have extremely a lot of HTML or conditionals in the JSP file. You need to split the JSP file in smaller parts which you include by `<jsp:include>`. For example one JSP include file per header, footer, menu, body and/or conditionally displayed parts, etc. It has the additional advantage that it's better reuseable.

Or, perhaps you followed the discouraged oldschool bad practice of writing raw Java code inside the JSP file using *scriptlets* (those `<% %>` things), while that Java code actually belongs in normal Java classes. [Get rid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) of all that Java code in JSP and move it into a fullworthy [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) class then. Therein you have all the freedom to write nicely reuseable classes/methods instead of putting the entire thing inside one large  unmaintainable "God" block.

Comment: Ah the old try-block limitation, an error everyone sooner or later will run into and learn proper JSP coding the hard way :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.

in standlone.xml, under web subsystem ->  configuration add keep-generated=false.

It worked for me.